# Is it possible to run a command from one ec2 instance that executes that command onto another ec2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Right now I am testing to see if I am able to write

```
touch test.txt
```

simply to another ec2 instance.
I have looked into both ssh and ssm but I do not understand where to begin the code. Any ideas to remotely send commands?

Comment: There are several different ways depending on your security setup.  Do the two EC2 instances trust each other?  A simple way is [shown here](https://serverfault.com/questions/215756/how-do-i-run-a-local-bash-script-on-remote-machines-via-ssh) but you could also have an HTTP server of some sort or may other ways.  What are you ultimately trying to build?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send a command remotely you can make use of the [AWS run command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/execute-remote-commands.html) functionality of SSM.

To do this you will need to ensure that you’re both running SSM agent and have a valid IAM role setup on the remote instance. The [getting started](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/getting-started.html) section should help that.

Finally you can call the remote instance using the [send-command](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ssm/send-command.html) function. Either [create your own document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/create-ssm-doc.html) or use the existing ‘AWS-RunShellScript’ document.